# how can i execute html tag on jsp page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

i want to execute paragraph tag on jsp page from the servlet response.I am able to execute alert of javascript but failed to execute below code. it is redirecting to servlet and then getting execute. I want below code in NewFile.jsp any solution for this.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");//setting the content type  
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();//get the stream to write the data  


    out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
    out.println("document.write(\"<p>Hello JavaScript by JavaScript</p>\");");
    out.println("location='NewFile.jsp';");
    out.println("</script>");
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: As soon as `location='NewFile.jsp';` executes, the web browser is going to load *a new page*. The `document.write(...` will have worked, but it will have added the HTML to the *old page* that you leave immediately after that.

Comment: i did not understand what you want say.